# Getting the words between a pattern in a String in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML which is server side rendered in the form of a string. 
I have to find the occurrence of `hello MyComponent hello-end` in the string.

There can be multiple instances of the above mentioned string with the value changing as per

```
hello FirstComponent hello-end
hello SecondComponent hello-end
hello ThirdComponent hello-end
```

and so on. 
I need to pass the string (that starts with hello Component(s) hello-end) to a seperate function with all occurrences of the the above pattern in the string.

I do know that there needs to be a loop but I am not very sure about this.
I am doing this in Javascript.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried something?  Are you stuck on something?

Comment: Idk what you're trying to do but it sounds terrible lol. what @GeorgeJempty said.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I was referring to the post, not your comment. Meaning that I wasn't sure the reason behind the question, and feel like any good solution shouldnt involve what the OP is trying to do.  And I was backing up your comment, even up voted it lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a better way to do it:

```js
let text = `Some text here
hello FirstComponent hello-end a bit more text here
hello SecondComponent hello-end a bit more text there
hello ThirdComponent hello-end
some text there`

function extractContent(input, startTag, endTag) {
  const re = new RegExp("("+ startTag + ")(.|\n)+?(" + endTag + ")", 'g');
  const result = [];
  let match;

  while ((match = re.exec(input)) !== null) {
    result.push(match[0]);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(extractContent(text, "hello", "hello-end"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

```
hello [a-zA-Z]+component hello-end
```

> Explanation

- `hello` - Matches `hello`.
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - Matches any character from a to z one or more time.
- `hello-end` - Matches `hello-end`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/X3wwNq/1)

```js
const regex = /hello [a-zA-Z]+component hello-end/gmi;
const str = `hello FirstComponent hello-end
hello SecondComponent hello-end
hello ThirdComponent hello-end
hello cn hello-end
hello firstcomponent hello`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a quick and dirty way to create an array of all text between "hello" and "hello-end":

```js
    let text = `Some text here
    hello FirstComponent hello-end a bit more text here
    hello SecondComponent hello-end a bit more text there
    hello ThirdComponent hello-end
    some text there`

    function parse(input) {
      let result = [];
      let s = input.split("hello");

      for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (/^-end/.test(s[i+1])) {
          result.push("hello" + s[i] + "hello-end");
        }
      }
      return result;
    }
    
    console.log(parse(text));
```

The after running `parse(input)` the `result` should be an array:

`["hello FirstComponent hello-end", "hello SecondComponent hello-end", "hello ThirdComponent hello-end" ]`

Comment: @Kresimir
I also want the hello and hello-end added to the array along with the componentName that is generated